# How can you capture logs from a Quectel eg91 module?

Tags: logging, quectel

I need to capture logs from a Quectel series EG91 module to send the activity to Quectel for further analysis. In the past, I sent an AT command to enable logging and used WinSCP to extract the logs. However, I cannot find the anything that says the EG91 series supports the same command.

Answer (score 0):

for modem log， you can use qwinlog.exe（quectel provide）to capture. if you want to capture linux log, may need implement by yourself.